# Three columns header with nav

Tags: html, css

I am in need of help regarding a three columns header with an image.

I need that the middle column be able to hold an image that has the dimension 166px x 156px. I want to have navigation in the right and left columns. All of the columns header will contain a background-color of black.

The nav is a drop down menu and as much as I toggle with it, I cannot make all of the 4 go horizontally across the page, resting at the same height on the page next to the image and the entire thing centered.

The code I currently have is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="central"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>


.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    display: table;
}
.central {
    width:166px;
    height:156px;
    background-color:#000;
    display: table-cell;
}
.left, .right {
    height:156px;        
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:#000;
}
.right {
    background-color:#000;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Can you please let us know what do you want to do and where is the problem

Comment: The nav is a drop down menu and as much as I toggle with it, I cannot make all of the 4 go horizontally across the page, resting at the same height on the page next to the image.

Comment: @LydiaMorales you need to be more clear in the definition of your problem. Doing a simple copy-n-paste from your original question for a response to a question in comments for more information for the people who are *trying to help you* does not suffice. Please provide more details, add some code (jsFiddle) or possibly a simple diagram of current state vs desired state. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check with the below CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}
.central {
    float: left;
    width:166px;
    height:156px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.left, .right {
        float: left;
    height:156px;
    width: 30%;
    background-color:#000;
}
.right {
    background-color:#000;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```